# Generate Artificial Data for Small Infrared Object Detection Task

Tags: object-detection, generative-adversarial-network, data-augmentation, infrared

I want to use GANs to generate artificial data or do data augmentation for object detection tasks, especially "small object detection" in "infrared space", such as detecting drones at night (as same as the ANTI-UAV challenge).
I need to generate drone images with GANs in infrared space and put them into the desired position in the background, I also need labels and annotations of drones to be generated automatically.
I need some instructions or guidance for this task.

I tried to find some repositories or papers but didn't find any good resources.
If you know something, a repository or a paper with its code, introduce it.

thank you.

Comment: Is there anyone who can assist me? I require some help.